# iOS app: UIButton tag not available in controller code

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder

I wrote a method to change the font to all controls of the viewcontroller. The method gets the root view of the viewcontroller and recursively iterates over all views to change the font. To know text style that has to be applied to the text I set a code  from Interface Builder to the tag property of each control. Everything works fine except for UIButton instances. UIButtons has no IBOutlet because I don't need any explicit references to them in the code. The problem is my controller can not retrieve the button tag value by using:

```
int viewTag = [view tag];
```

It is always 0 no matter what I set in Interface Builder. Why?

Here a code snippet of the code I use:

**FontManager class**

```
+ (void)setCustomFontToView:(UIView *)view {

    if ( [view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]] &&
         [view respondsToSelector:@selector(setFont:)]  ) {

        int viewTag = [view tag];

        UIFont *font = nil;

        if ( viewTag == 1 ) {

            font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Frutiger-Light" size:18];

        } else if ( viewTag == 2 ) {

            font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Frutiger-Bold" size:20];
        }

        [(UILabel *) view setFont:font];
    }

    NSArray *childViews = [view subviews];

    if ( [childViews count] > 0 ) {

        for ( UIView *childView in childViews ) {
            [self setCustomFontToView:childView];
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     .....
     [FontManager setCustomFontToView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try adding an `IBOutlet` for it?

Comment: You said you didn't make an IBOutlet to the button, so what is myButton?

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight the goal of automating the process is precisely to avoid having to create an IBOutlet for each control :$ . @ rdelmar see my edit (sorry for mistake)

Comment: You have [view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class], so wouldn't that cause your code to only change the font of labels?

Comment: i think you should try to use appearance proxy to change your fonts more effectively

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting tag value for UIButton not UILabel that is its child. Thats why it always returns 0. Add a check for UIButton and tag, than set font to title label.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to create an IBOutletCollection? I think your tag is set to the UIButton, not on the label, and tags aren't defaulted up the view hierarchy.

You select multiple buttons in IB and control drag it into a header, the collection outputs as an NSArray of buttons and you can iterate through that to change the fonts.

This way there's less iterations required to do the work. There's really no performance impact linking a collection of the buttons but there's a performance impact in iterating through every subview of the hierarchy checking if you can even change a label.